# Palindrome2 loop not working

Tags: c++

In the program I am pasting the palindrome2 function is not working correctly in the loop as max2 is giving the output 998000(upper limit of for loop) whereas for an individual number '1441' its working just fine and giving the output as 1.Can you please guide???

```
#include <iostream>
long palindrome1(long);
long palindrome2(long);

int main()
{
    using namespace std;
    long a,b=111,max1=0,max2=0;
    for(b=111;b<998001;b++)
    {
      if((palindrome2(b))==1)
      {
          max2=b;
      }
    }
    for(a=11;a<998001;a++)
    {
        if((palindrome2(a))==1)
        {
          max1=a;
        }
    }
     cout<<max1<<endl;
     cout<<max2<<endl;
     cout<<palindrome2(1441)<<endl;
     cin.clear();
     cin.get();
}
long palindrome2(long n)
{
    long a[6],b,c=0;
    do {
        a[c]=n%10;
        n=n/10;
        c++;
    } while(n>0);

    b=c;
    if(b%2!=0)
    {
        for(int l=b/2;l>=0;l--)
            for(int m=(b/2)+1;m<=b;m++)
            {
                if(a[l]!=a[m])
                {
                    return 0;
                    break;
                }
            }
    }
    else
    {
        return 1;   
    }
}

long palindrome1(long n)
{
    long a[6],b,c=0;
    do {
        a[c]=n%10;
        n=n/10;
        c++;
    } while(n>0);

    b=c;
    if(b%2==0)
    {
        for(int k=(b/2)-1;k>=0;k--)
            for(int d=((b/2)+1);d<=b;d++)
            {
                if(a[k]==a[d])
                {
                    return 0;
                    break;
                }
            }
    }
    else
    {
        return 1;   
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't quite understand what "palindrome2" is supposed to do in the first place.

Comment: yeah its working just fine only not in a loop

Comment: Indented the code correctly... You don't have a whole set of warnings when you compile ?

Comment: @PetriucFlorin yep you are right palindrome 2 is completely wrong

Comment: i guess ill delete the question sorry for wasting your precious time people :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't look at the loop boundary cases but there are some outright errors : you are returning 1 for all even length numbers. That can't be correct. 
Also, for odd length numbers, you immediately return 0 for mismatches, but do not return a 1 in case everything matches (the else part is skipped, in case thats what you were thinking).

Basically, palindrome2( 10 ) will return 1, and palindrome2( 101 ) will return return some garbage value (its a technical term).

Comment: yes you are right palindrome 2 is fully wrong.palindrome 1 is working fine though